# AngularJS v2 is not a function?

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple piece of code to run a dynamic `sortBy` over my array.  I am using a `select` with `ng-model` to return the correct key by which to sort.  However, I can change the select once, and the orderBy works. But once I do it again, I get a very strange error

Controller

```
//change task sort
$scope.changeOrder = 'task_date';
$scope.changeOrder = (filterTask) => {
  if (filterTask == "due") {
    $scope.changeOrder = 'task_date';
  } else if (filterTask == "imp")  {
    $scope.changeOrder = 'task_importence';
  }
};
```

Template

```
        <select ng-change=changeOrder(filterTask) ng-model="filterTask">
          <option value="due">Due First</option>
          <option value="imp">Importance</option>
        </select>

       <task-item ng-repeat="task in $ctrl.user.task | orderBy : changeOrder"></task-item>
```

Here is the error - There is nothing called "v2" in my system [image: typeerrror]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the untyped world that is JavaScript.

Your error is actually quite apparent: `$scope.changeOrder` becomes a function *and* a standard variable.  Once you select a value in your select drop-down, it ceases to be a function and reverts to a standard variable.  Then, you can no longer call it.

You would be wise to split this up into two variables instead.  I'd recommend using `$scope.orderState` and `$scope.changeOrder`, where `orderState` just holds the strings and `changeOrder` is your function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that both of your $scope variables have the same name. You try to assign a function and a value to $scope.changeOrder. Try splitting it up into two variables